# SharePoint 2013 App, access version history on host web list item

Tags: angularjs, sharepoint, sharepoint-2013

I am creating a Angular Sharepoint hosted app for a client.
I have a list in the host web where i will store information, the input will be in the App.
I am trying to get the version history on items from the host web list witout much luck.
I have tried the two options: 
The SPService option:

```
$().SPServices({
    operation: "GetVersionCollection",
    async: false,
    strlistID: "TestList",
    strlistItemID: 36,
    strFieldName: "Description",
    completefunc: function (xData, Status) {
        $(xData.responseText).find("Version").each(function (i) {
            console.log("Name: " + $(this).attr("Description") + " Modified: " + $(this).attr("Modified"));
        });
    }
});
```

Above code doesnt work because the list is in the host web, anyone know how to configure the code above to access the host web list? 
The "Versions.aspx" option:

```
    function getItemVersions(url,listId,itemId,success)
{
       var versionsUrl = url + '/_layouts/versions.aspx?list=' + listId + '&ID=' + itemId;  
       $.get( versionsUrl, function( data ) {
          var versionEntries = parseVersionsData(data);
          success(versionEntries);
       });
}
    function parseVersionsData(data){
       var entries = {};
       var versionList = $(data).find('table.ms-settingsframe');


       versionList.find('> tbody > tr').each(function(i){
         if(i > 0 && (i) % 2 == 0) {
            var verRow = $(this); //get version row
            var propsRow = verRow.next(); //get properties row
            var versionLabel = verRow.find('td:first').html().trim();
            if(versionLabel.length > 0) {
              entries[versionLabel] = {};
              //extract item version properties
              propsRow.find('tr').each(function(i){
                var pName = $(this).find('td:nth-child(1)').text().trim();
                var pVal = $(this).find('td:nth-child(2)').text().trim();
                entries[versionLabel][pName] = pVal; 
              });
            }      
         }

       });   
       return entries;
}
```

The above code gets the error: 
"No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource."

Yet again i am unsure how to config the code so that it can access the host web list.
If someone has another way to get the version history to an app i would appreciate it.

Answer (score 0):

Probably you need to edit your App manifest to allow your app to access the "parent" web. This is a security feature - apps are running from a different domain than the main site (thus you get the "cross-origin-policy" error). Users must first (on installation) agree to all requested permissions, and only then you can use SharePoint API to access lists on the parent site.

That is, if your application wants to access Lists from the parent site, it's manfiest should explicitly say so (in VisualStudio, check the "AppManfiest.xml" file).

Also, you may probably consider using standard SharePoint API to communicate with SharePoint (Client Side Object Model, aka CSOM)? But I'm not sure what library you use to communicate with SharePoint, maybe it's already like that.

Comment: I have given full controll in the app manifest so that is not the problem.Client Object Model doesn't provide versions property (which is available only on Server Side Object Model)

Comment: Sorry, I missed that point. Right, using CSOM you can get version of files (File.Versions), but not of plain list items :( 
No idea how to do that.